# Распределение памяти в функции C++

Tags: c++

Имеется такая функция

```
void func(){

    int a = 999999;
    int b = 999988;
    int c = 999977;
    int d = 999966;
    int arr[100];
    int *y = &arr[0];
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){

        arr[i] = 111111;

    }


    for (int i=0; i<115; i++){
        cout.width(10);
        cout<<*(y+i)<<" "<<(y+i)<<endl;

    }   


}
```

Она выводит массив и сделующие за ним ячейки памяти, элементы массива идут друг за другом, это естественно. После них 2 ячейки, то есть 8 байт остаются пустыми и идут следующие 4 переменные (a,b,c,d). Если удалить одну перепенную и оставить (a,b,c), то это расстояние увеличиваеся до 3 ячеек, то есть 12 байт, а если оставить одну переменную (a), то это расстояние увеличится до 5 ячеек и соотственно 40 байт. У меня вопрос, почему так распределяется память? От чего это зависит? У меня операционка Windows 10 (64bit).
Предполагаяю, что 8 байт уходят на указатель, но куда уходят остальные непонятно.

Comment: Компилятор может просто выпилить неиспользуемые переменные, а все остальные перемешать по адресам.

Comment: "После них 2 ячейки, то есть 8 байт" и "увеличится до 5 ячеек и соотственно 40 байт", что вы подразумваете под ячейкой? И какого объёма ячейка?

Comment: @Unick По ячейкой подразумеваю 4 байта, выделенные под тип Int. Если переменных оставить четыре(a,b,c,d) как в коде выше, то расстояние в памяти между ними и массивом будет 8 байт, если переменная будет одна(только a), то расстояние от нее до массива будет 40 байт, почему так происходит непонятно, также если добавить переменную, чтобы их стало 5 (a,b,c,d,e), то это расстояние станет равным 40 байт

Comment: Вообще-то компилятор может это все перепутывать, как бог на душу положит - например, чтоб взлом затруднить. А вообще - ну гляньте ассемблерный код, все будет понятно...

Comment: @alexolut Но тут есть прямая закономерность и каждый раз происходит одно и тоже, думаете это происходит из-за компилятора, а не из-за распределения памяти операционной системой?

Comment: А какой компилятор и какие настройки?

Comment: @Unick В Dev-C++ и в codeblocks сейчас попробовал, не знаю какие комплияторы, но результаты в памяти получаются совершенно разные. CodeBlocks все сплошником выдает, без разницы сколько переменных. В общем понятно, что это распределение зависит от компилятора. Спасибо

Comment: @Kotysh, маленький совет для будущих исследований подобного рода. Просто печатайте **адреса** интересующих вас переменных.

Comment: @avp В коде выше я печатаю адреса, но все равно было непонятно, Вы кстати солидарны с ответом, что это зависит от компилятора?

Comment: @Kotysh, распределением памяти в стеке (а ваши переменные, с так называемым автоматическим классом памяти размещаются в нем) безусловно зависит только от компилятора. Некоторые компиляторы применяют к размещению массивов особые правила выравнивания (более жесткие, чем к остальным переменным того же типа).

Comment: @avp теперь все точно ясно, спасибо

Comment: Вообще ващи переменные a, b, c, d нигде в коде не используются. Наверное при компиляции со всеми оптимизациями их должны выбросить. Кстати я думаю вы можете настроить параметры так, чтобы кроме объектника генерился ассемлбер файл, по которому может быть легче понять, что происходит.